# Single scrollbar for split view HTML

Tags: html, css

I've created a split view to divide my webpage into a left and right side. Currently, the left portion contains a textarea for user input and the right side mimics whatever the user has typed. The problem I'm now facing is that once the textarea expands to be larger than the user's view, the two sides of the webpage have independent scrollbars (as seen in the image). I'd like to make it so that the webpage has a single scrollbar to control both views, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

[image: scrollbars]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sCalc</title>

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/styles.css">

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script>
    delete module.exports
  </script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="./window.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>


<body>
  <div id="container" class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Input row -->
    <div class="split left">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
        <h3 class="hash-heading">Input</h3>
        <textarea id="text-input" class="form-control text-input" style="overflow:hidden" placeholder="Enter text and see the results..."></textarea>

        <!-- Script handling auto resize of input box -->
        <script>
          var textarea = document.getElementById("text-input");

          textarea.oninput = function() {
            textarea.style.height = "";
            textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight) + "px";
          };
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Output row -->
    <div class="split right">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="hash-heading">Output</h3>
        <pre id="usrOutput" class="hash-output"> </pre>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.split {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `position: fixed` to split the screen, use a flexbox. When you add lines to the textarea pane, the other pane will stretch as well, and you'll have a single scrollbar:

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  background-color: white;
}

.right {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="container" class="container-fluid">

  <!-- Input row -->
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">
      <h3 class="hash-heading">Input</h3>
      <textarea id="text-input" class="form-control text-input" placeholder="Enter text and see the results..."></textarea>

      <!-- Script handling auto resize of input box -->
      <script>
        var textarea = document.getElementById("text-input");

        textarea.oninput = function() {
          textarea.style.height = "";
          textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight) + "px";
        };
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Output row -->
  <div class="split right">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h3 class="hash-heading">Output</h3>
      <pre id="usrOutput" class="hash-output"> </pre>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```